# Multidrop RS232 - Diode selection and doubts

Tags: diodes, rs232

i'm currently using this reference schematic to wire up 10 RS232 slaves in a "multidrop" configuration (The slaves are some ATMEGA328P with MAX232 Trancievers in order to make a real RS232 network).

[image: Multidrop net]

I have some doubts regarding the diode to put on TX line of slaves: i've tried using LL4148 ([Datasheet here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Switching-Diode_ST-Semtech-LL4148_C9808.html)) but nothing works, the slaves will not work as expected.

So, i've taken a BZX85C5V1 Zener diode and i've replaced the LL4148, now the slave works as expected: receiving and sending messages to the master.

What i'm missing? maybe i've chosen a wrong diode (LL4148)? which diode i can use in this multidrop serial network configuration? Why 5V a zener (BZX85C5V1) works?

Comment: RS232 is not a multidrop bus so this is not the intended use case for it. At what speed you are trying to communicate? How long is the bus, if there are 11 devices in total? What is the master/host of the bus, does it have MAX232 as well or something else? Are the diodes the correct way around?

Comment: Yes, there are 11 devices in total, each slave has an atmega 328p with respective diode on tx line. The master is an ESP32 with relative Max 3232 without diode on TX and RX. As master, it's only swapped the Rx and TX swapped to the slaves

Comment: The outputs of the Max232 are bipolar ( +/- 12v ) so a diode 4148 does not work unless you add a pulldown resistor to -12v (you can take it from one of the max232). The zener is not the best solution.

Comment: Why? So a pulldown resistor on the tx line? After or before diode? How this can work? I mean, the Max232 creates a standard RS232 bus...why just using the posted schematic it won't work? Please add some details, I really want to understand that!

Comment: @PaulGhobril Output of MAX232 is not +/-12V, they are typically only +/-7V. And RS232 inputs typically don't need -12V, almost all of them consider 0V low enough voltage, same as disconnecting the wire. Besides the MAX3232 receiver has the typical 5kohm resistance to ground. Virtapp, please add baud rate and bus length.

Comment: Sure, the baud rate is 38400 bps and the maximum bus length is 10 meters.

Comment: @justme although the threshold is 0.6v as per max  232 datasheet considering 0v is a bad choice since it is meant to be bipolar to reduce the noise effect.

Comment: @VirtApp the resistor must be at the master RX. A pulldown is needed because at idle (all slave outputs to -V all diodes are open circuit and the Master RX will be connected to ground through the RX resistor typ 5k. The zener solution is bad because from one side you have an asymetric bipolar signal and from the other side you will have an excessive current curculating between Tx outputs

Comment: 10 meters of what kind of cable? Twisted pair, something else? How much capacitance the cable has? @PaulGhobril The MAX3232 receiver input has schmitt trigger so it has hysteresis and 0.6V is only the the minimum for low-going threshold. Typically the threshold is 1.2V with 0.3V hysteresis. If the asymmetric drive with cable capacitance is the issue, it can help to discharge the capacitance though. But in reality, RS232 tranceivers are really meant for one-to-one connection, a driver is not meant for multidrop, so the driver may have trouble driving 10 receivers too.

Comment: It's a twisted pair cat5e cable, the 10 slave number is the maximum number, typically they are 7/8. Also the cable, 10 meters is the maximum length, typically it doesn't exceeds 5 meters.

Comment: @PaulGhobril, i've tried using a pulldown resistor on Master RX, nothing changed. The system won't communicate.

Comment: Make sure of diodes polarity. Maybe you did but I am trying to help. Where did you comnect the other end of the pulldown resistor.

Comment: The diode is placed as reported in this image: https://ibb.co/Y3Q2g6L - The pulldown resistor is placed in the RX output of MAX3232 master device

Comment: @PaulGhobril, i've forgot to tell you the resistor value, it's a 2.7k

Comment: There is something wrong in the image. The diode must be at the output of each slave. Is this the max232 at the master? Can you show the complete circuit diagram

Comment: Sorry...my bad, this is the MAX232 that is placed near every ATMEGA on all slaves, here the images: the first two images represents the slaves and second an last image the master: 
https://ibb.co/8XThGdP
https://ibb.co/4dnmt9p
https://ibb.co/6Fsr8DW
https://ibb.co/59R0YLW

Comment: the circuit is not coherent with the diagram in the question. Tx of each Slave must be connected through a diode to the RX of the master. the Tx of the master must be applied to RX of the slaves

Comment: It's already wired as you reported, here the connector diagram: The first is the slave connector and the second is the master connector https://ibb.co/4P6MrLb
https://ibb.co/qCZ68q1

Answer (score 1):

The diode is on pin 13 and that is the wrong pin as that is the RS232 input pin R1IN on MAX232. Diode should be on pin 14, which is the RS232 output pin T1OUT.